# git merge does not contain my changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two git branches B1 and B2. B2 has the newest copy of my file F. When I merge B2 into B1 ( `git checkout B1 && git merge B2` ) the log for F ( `git log F`) does not contain any of the commits that had been done on B2. I only see commits C1-C3 that existed previously on B1. But when I do (`git log --follow F`) I see the commits on B1 from B2, C4-C6. However when I open the file F to inspect it it does not contain those changes from commits C4-C6. What's going on?

Comment: Does running `git log --graph --oneline` shed any light?

Comment: No, unfortunately the history is quite complicated with other merges so I find it very tricky to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use "follow" unless you renamed the file. Try `git log B1 -- F` to just filter on whether a commit affected that file.

Also use `git blame F` to see what commits the current lines in the file came from.

As you say the history is quite complicated. If there were conflicts in merges, you could have accepted the "theirs" side of a conflict and that would erase the visibility of changes introduced in the current branches history.

Comment: I tracked it down to a merge conflict involving F. I'm not sure why yet but it seems the state of F in B1 was preferred and the changes to F in B2 was thrown away. Oddly the blob for the merge conflict does not show anything in the diff.

Comment: Conflicts will be reported by the patch view of a merge commit. Double check in gitk.

Comment: Ya I saw in the log message that there was a conflict on file F but there was no diff in the commit blob. I suspect that's normal because during the conflict resolution the 'ours' version of the file was chosen over the 'theirs' copy so there was no diff...?

Comment: I haven't delved into how exactly the patch for a merge is made, but I suspect you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem after creating a branch and merging, the problem is that git does a fast-forward when your master is reachable from the branch.

To log this you have the argument

```
git merge --no-ff B2
```

Good luck.